# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'start' (wxPython)

Tags: python, wxpython, attributeerror

I am making a simple text editor to get the basics of GUI programming. I am using wxPython.

> When I run **main.py**, a window will pop up with the buttons READ and WRITE, READ being for opening and reading files, and WRITE being for editing files. The `wx.Frame` classes for those are in **read.py** and **write.py** respectively.

The function `k()` works fine, there is no error with `write.write()`, but I get an **AttributeError** with `read.read()`, which I had originally in `l()`.

I changed the line to `read.start()`, and in **read.py** I added the function `start()` which makes an instance of the class `read`, because I thought that maybe it wasn't executing because it was a class, just to be sure.

Still, I am getting the error: **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'start'**

**main.py**

```
import wx
import read
import write

def l(self):
    read.start()                    # getting error

def k(self):
    write.write()


app = wx.App()
first = wx.Dialog(None, -1, title='title', size=(200, 100))
panel = wx.Panel(first, -1)
panel.SetBackgroundColour('black')
bt1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'READ', size=(100, 100), pos=(1, 1))
bt1.SetBackgroundColour('green')
bt2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'WRITE', size=(100, 100), pos=(1, 2))
bt2.SetBackgroundColour('red')
first.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, l, bt1)     # when bt1 is clicked, l() is executed
first.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, k, bt2)     # when bt2 is clicked, k() is executed

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

sizer.Add(bt1, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(bt2, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_VERTICAL)
panel.SetSizer(sizer)
first.Centre()
first.ShowModal()
app.MainLoop()
```

**read.py**

```
import os
import main

def start():
    l = read()                        # makes instance of class read()

class read(wx.Frame):
    blah
```

**write.py**

```
import wx
import os
import main

class write(wx.Frame):                 # there is no start function, but still works
    bleh
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to import wx in your read.py.
after you have  added this import line, remove the start thing and try again with read.read(). 
The First read is the filename and second read after dot is classname.

Comment: THANK YOU for catching me not importing wx, but unfortunately, it still isn't working when I do read.read()

Comment: You have multiple mistakes in your code. Do you have serious stuff in your read class or really just bleh? Why are you expecting self as argument in your k and l function?

Comment: Oh haha I'm sorry, I took out most of the code just because A) It would be way too much to read, unless you actually want to see all of it and B) I know the class works because when I put it in one file (instead of putting the classes and everything else in one file) the GUI and everything works fine. I don't actually have 'bleh' in there. Also, I have **self** as an argument because in wxPython when you `Bind` an event to a button, when the button is pressed, self is automatically passed as an argument.

Comment: Is read.py in a subdirectory? The subdirectory needs a file with name __init__.py

Comment: Hm it's [underline][underline]init[underline][underline].py

Comment: yeah I have all that stuff. They're in the same directory, and the folder also has an __init__.py. It's really weird, because write.py and read.py are almost identical besides the actual GUI program.

Comment: I've found something interesting. If I make a random python file, I did **srs.py** randomly, and have the lines `import read`, `import write`, and `import main`, and I add a fourth line that does nothing (e.g. var = 'string'), and I run that file, the program works fine. It's just that when I run **main.py**, it gives the attribute error for read.read(). Can you come up with anything?

Comment: Hm i searched a bit and found that it could be because you named your file and class like a default module in python "read" try to name it "myread" or similar. Filename myread and class myread: myread.myread ()

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but it's still not working. I think I'll just do what works, in that use that **srs.py** file I mentioned earlier. Thank you though!